# How to split data into train and test keeping in mind the groupby column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, train-test-split

I would like to split the data set into test and train dataset in the ratio 20:80. However, while splitting, I do not want to split in a manner that 1 S_Id value has few data points in train and other data points in test.

I have a dataset as:

```
S_Id      Datetime               Item      
1         29-06-2018 03:23:00    654
1         29-06-2018 04:01:00    452
1         29-06-2018 04:25:00    101
2         30-06-2018 05:17:00    088
2         30-06-2018 05:43:00    131
3         30-06-2018 10:36:00    013
3         30-06-2018 11:19:00    092
```

I would like to split neatly as something like:
Train:

```
S_Id      Datetime               Item      
1         29-06-2018 03:23:00    654
1         29-06-2018 04:01:00    452
1         29-06-2018 04:25:00    101
2         30-06-2018 05:17:00    088
2         30-06-2018 05:43:00    131
```

Test:

```
S_Id      Datetime               Item 
3         30-06-2018 10:36:00    013
3         30-06-2018 11:19:00    092
```

All same S_Ids must be in one set. Can it be done through simple 'groupby'?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a direct function that does so, so you could write a customized one :

```py
def sample_(we_array, train_size):
    """
     we_array : used as the weight of each unique element on your S_id column, 
     it's normalized to represent a probability

    """
    idx = np.arange(we_array.size) #get the index for each element on the array
    np.random.shuffle(idx) #shuffle it 
    cum = we_array[idx].cumsum()  
    train_idx = idx[cum<train_size]# we take the first elements until we have  
                                   # our desired size
    test_idx = idx[cum>=train_size]
    return train_idx, test_idx

idx = df.S_Id.values
unique, counts = np.unique(idx, return_counts = True) # we access the unique 
                                                      # elements and their cout
probability = counts/counts.sum()
train_idx, test_idx = sample_(probability, 0.8)
train = df[df.S_Id.isin(unique[train_idx])] 
test = df[df.S_Id.isin(unique[test_idx])]
```

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help

Answer (score 0):

If S_Id is dataframe's index, you can simply get it using:

```
df.loc[3]
```

If it's not the case, you can set it as index and then loc, as:

```
df.set_index(S_Id).loc[3]
```

This should return dataframe containing all rows with S_Id equal to 3.